# Transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] - Gas fee

Tags: nodejs, gnosis-safe, polygon, safe-core-sdk

I'm trying to create new safe wallet for my current wallet using deploySafe method. Following is my implementation:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('https://polygon-rpc.com);
const ownerSigner = new ethers.Wallet(this.METAMASK_PRIVATE_KEY, provider);
const ethAdapter = new EthersAdapter({
  ethers,
  signerOrProvider: ownerSigner,
});
const safeFactory = await SafeFactory.create({
  ethAdapter,
});

const safeAccountConfig: SafeAccountConfig = {
  owners: [await ownerSigner.getAddress()],
  threshold: 1,
};

const gasPriceNew = Number(ethers.utils.parseUnits('200', 'gwei')); // Set a custom gas price in Gwei
const newWallet = await safeFactory.deploySafe({
  safeAccountConfig,
  options: {
    gasPrice: gasPriceNew,
    gasLimit: 1000000,
  },
  callback: (txHash: string): void => {
    console.log('Create wallet txHash:', txHash);
  },
});
const newAddress = await newWallet.getAddress();

return newAddress;
```

I got error:

Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]

1. How to define gas fee and gas limit for deploySafe transaction in Polygon network?
2. I cannot make deploySafe without optionsm it throws error about absence of gas gee.
3. Sometimes the transaction works well, but it is 1 of 10 with the same settings. How to make it stable?

Comment: there must be some gas configuration issue...
Its better to share this question here.. https://t.me/blockchainworldco/
its a group of web3 devs... the might be able to help

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using ethers v5, while the latest version of the SDK uses ethers v6. I would suggest to update to the latest packages, and retry without the `options` parameter, as the SDK calculates them internally. Another thing also is to provide `saltNonce`, in order to make sure that each try resolves to a different eth address.

Hope it helps! Louis